# Loop with 2 offsets

Tags: excel, vba

done quite a bit of research and I cannot quite figure this out..
This is one workbook, searching between Sheet "Quote" and sheet "Export"

This script should be

- searching for "PartNum" starting in Quote sheet once found
- moves down 2 cells
- Copies the value on the new active cell
- searches for that value in worksheet "export"
- once found copies the value offset 24 cells to the right
- returns to worksheet "quote"
- Finds "Leadtime"
- move down 2 cells and pastes the value

The part i'm stuck on, I didn't write this correctly to loop as i would like, how can i accurately loop 1 row lower each time for BOTH Partnum and Leadtime? Is there any way I can add so it ignores if a part is not found instead of erroring out?

```
   'Find PartNum
Worksheets("Quote").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="PartNum").Offset(2, 0).Select

'Copy/search part Num

   Dim str1 As String
    Dim Cntr As Integer
    Cntr = 0
    Do While Cntr <= 650

      Cntr = Cntr + 1
      str1 = ActiveCell.Value
      Selection.Copy

      Worksheets("Export").Activate
      ActiveCell.Select
      Cells.Find(What:=str1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Range("A1").Select
      Selection.Copy

      Worksheets("Quote").Activate
     
     
'Find PartNum
Cells.Find(What:="Leadtime").Offset(2, 0).Select
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation of exactly what workbooks (multiple?) and worksheets are in use here.   Also worth reviewing this post to get away from using Select/Activate in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999

Comment: I've cleaned up the explanation, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You want the second instance of `str1` on "Export"?  That's why the `FindNext` ?

Comment: Also not clear what the purpose of the `Do While Cntr <= 650` loop is

Comment: Sharing screenshots of your worksheets might clarify a lot. Don't you know the row or column where to find `ParNum` and `Leadtime`?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try.

RE: how can i accurately loop 1 row lower each time for BOTH Partnum and Leadtime?

```
Use ".Offset(3, 0).Select"
```

RE: Part not found

replace "Cells.Find(What:="PartNum").Offset(2, 0).Select" with:

```
Dim PN As Range
Set PN = Cells.Find(What:="PartNum")

If PN Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Part Number is not found")
    'Exit Sub?
End If

PN.Offset(3, 0).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can gather from your posted code, but need some clarification around what you're doing on "export" sheet...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()

    Dim wsQuote As Worksheet, wsExport As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim str1 As String, f As Range, f2 As Range
    
    'use an explicit workbook reference
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook for example
    Set wsQuote = wb.Worksheets("Quote")
    Set wsExport = wb.Worksheets("Export")

    Set f = FindWholeValue(wsQuote.Cells, "PartNum")
    If f Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    str1 = f.Offset(2, 0).Value 'two rows down from "PartNum"

    '------------------
    'Can't figure out what you're doing on the Export sheet...
    '
    '  Set f2 = ???
    '------------------
    
    Set f = FindWholeValue(wsQuote.Cells, "Leadtime")
    If f Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    f.Offset(2, 0).Value = f2.Value
    
End Sub

'Search `rng` for `v` and return the first matched cell
'If not found and `WarnIfMissing` is True, warn the user
Function FindWholeValue(rng As Range, v, Optional WarnIfMissing As Boolean = True) As Range
    Set FindWholeValue = rng.Find(what:=v, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    If FindWholeValue Is Nothing And WarnIfMissing Then
        MsgBox "Value '" & v & "' not found on sheet '" & rng.Parent.Name & "'"
    End If
End Function
```